# ¿Como obtener los valores de un formulario en JavaScript de una mejor forma?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Me gustaría saber de qué manera puedo mejorar este código de jQuery, ya que en ocasiones no me recupera los valores, o incluso me recupera los valores de un dato anterior, es decir: en ocasiones no recupera los valores correspondientes. ¿Existe una mejor forma de lo que yo realice para recuperar los valores de un formulario?

Espero me puedan orientar de acuerdo a su experiencia, se los agradecería. Me gustaría mejorar mi código de acuerdo a sus experiencias. Para ir mejorando.

El siguiente código es de un crud que estoy realizando

```
 **$("#formReportes").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //evita el comportambiento normal del submit, es decir, recarga total de la página
    folio = $.trim($("#folio").val());
    nombre = $.trim($("#nombre").val());
    apellido = $.trim($("#apellido").val());
    direccion = $.trim($("#direccion").val());
    descripcion_domicilio = $.trim($("#descripcion_domicilio").val());
    telefono = $.trim($("#telefono").val());
    num_contrato = $.trim($("#num_contrato").val());
    fecha_inicio = $.trim($("#fecha_inicio").val());
    fecha_final = $.trim($("#fecha_final").val());
    cuadrilla = $.trim($("#cuadrilla").val());
    estatus = $.trim($("#estatus").val());
    observaciones = $.trim($("#observaciones").val());
    encargado_cuadrilla = $.trim($("#encargado_cuadrilla").val());
    otra_descripcion = $.trim($("#otra_descripcion").val());
    $.ajax({
      url: "../controlador/reportes.php",
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "json",
      data: {
        id: id,
        folio: folio,
        nombre: nombre,
        apellido: apellido,
        direccion: direccion,
        descripcion_domicilio: descripcion_domicilio,
        telefono: telefono,
        num_contrato: num_contrato,
        fecha_inicio: fecha_inicio,
        fecha_final: fecha_final,
        cuadrilla: cuadrilla,
        estatus: estatus,
        observaciones: observaciones,
        encargado_cuadrilla: encargado_cuadrilla,
        otra_descripcion: otra_descripcion,
        opcion: opcion,
      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        tablaReportes.ajax.reload(null, false);
      },
    });
    $("#modalCRUD").modal("hide");
  });
  //para limpiar los campos antes de dar de Alta una Persona
  $("#btnNuevo").click(function () {
    opcion = 1; //alta
    id = null;
    $("#formReportes").trigger("reset");
    $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#17a2b8");
    $(".modal-header").css("color", "white");
    $(".modal-title").text("Alta Reportes");
    $("#modalCRUD").modal("show");
  });
    //Editar
      $(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function () {
        opcion = 2; //editar
        fila = $(this).closest("tr");
        id = parseInt(fila.find("td:eq(0)").text()); //capturo el ID
        folio = fila.find("td:eq(1)").text();
        nombre = fila.find("td:eq(2)").text();
        apellido = fila.find("td:eq(3)").text();
        direccion = fila.find("td:eq(4)").text();
        descripcion_domicilio = fila.find("td:eq(5)").text();
        telefono = fila.find("td:eq(6)").text();
        num_contrato = fila.find("td:eq(7)").text();
        fecha_inicio = fila.find("td:eq(8)").text();
        fecha_final = fila.find("td:eq(9)").text();
        cuadrilla = fila.find("td:eq(10)").text();
        estatus = fila.find("td:eq(11)").text();
        observaciones = fila.find("td:eq(12)").text();
        encargado_cuadrilla = fila.find("td:eq(13)").text();
        otra_descripcion = fila.find("td:eq(14)").text();
        $("#folio").val(folio);
        $("#nombre").val(nombre);
        $("#apellido").val(apellido);
        $("#direccion").val(direccion);
        $("#descripcion_domicilio").val(descripcion_domicilio);
        $("#telefono").val(telefono);
        $("#num_contrato").val(num_contrato);
        $("#fecha_inicio").val(fecha_inicio);
        $("#fecha_final").val(fecha_final);
        $("#cuadrilla option:contains(" + cuadrilla + ")").attr("selected", "");
        $("#estatus option:contains(" + estatus + ")").attr("selected", "");
        $("#observaciones").val(observaciones);
        $("#encargado_cuadrilla").val(encargado_cuadrilla);
        $("#otra_descripcion").val(otra_descripcion);
        $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#007bff");
        $(".modal-header").css("color", "white");
        $(".modal-title").text("Editar Reporte");
        $("#modalCRUD").modal("show");
      });**
```

Comment: Si bien es una biblioteca de JavaScript, lo que estás usando aquí es _jQuery_. ¿Dónde estás llamando al script? No olvides mostrar un [repro]. Por cierto, no preguntes por "la mejor forma de" ya que estas preguntas están basadas en opiniones, y terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Lo agregué a mi código.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: no veo que relacion tiene esta pregunta con php, no veo codigo php alguno o algun error relacionado..

Comment: Esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones: *¿Existe una mejor forma de lo que yo realice para recuperar los valores de un formulario?* siempre hay una mejor forma dependiendo de quien y quienes respondan ... incluso te pueden recomendar cambiar el lenguaje de programacion o de plataforma y seria valido pero seria una discucion interminable...

Comment: Pues, se entiende que es engorroso, pero si así tienes armado el envío de la petición ajax, no hay mucho que hacer. Más bien, si tienes líos con los datos que se envían, ese sí puede ser un problema a revisar.

Comment: que es una mejor forma?

Comment: @gbianchi mejor código,

Comment: que es un mejor codigo? a mi ese codigo me parece legible...

Comment: Si bien la pregunta no es del todo clara, el OP expresa que su código tiene un problema, no le recupera los valores y en otras ocasiones cuando lo hace, lo hace de manera incorrecta. No veo que tenga de opinable esa situación. Por otro lado, también quiere mejorar su código, que puede referirse a legibilidad o a performance, ambas materias son de lo más importante en la programación, además que en ambos caso existen métricas para comprobar la mejora, o sea no hay nada que sea opinable. Y por último pedir la opinión a personas que tienen mayores conocimientos que uno debería ser aplaudido

Comment: Si sigues con problema, favor coloca el código completo javascript, html y php

Comment: @Yussef no se puede mejorar un cadigo a medias y sin saber que se quiere mejorar... es en base a cada quien que se quiera mejorar... si esta pregunta que tu dices que tiene que ver con refactorizar ... en code review puede ser el sitio en donde hacerla; por lo general las refactorizacion que se hacen aqui son muy especificas...

Comment: @Yussef tampoco tenemos el codigo HTML no podemos reproducir el error que tiene o que menciona el OP, por lo tanto hay que partir desde un inicio con que el OP aclare que  sucede realmente, por eso estamos especulando y opinando de todo menos de lo que realmente quiere el Op... esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones y debe ser cerrada. hasta que se tengan los elementos para dar una rerspuesta de calidad para el sitio.

Answer (score 5):

Aunque como comentan esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones te dejo un ejemplo, ya que todos estamos aprendiendo y se que aveces es complicado entender cuando vamos comenzando en el mundo de la programación, te recomiendo investigar mas del tema.

Si hay una forma mejor de obtener los valores de un **form**, veo que estas utilizando JQuery, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
//FUNCION QUE ENVIA EL FORMULARIO MEDIANTE AJAX, ESTE ESCRIPT DEBE IR AL FINAL DEL DOM 

//DETECTAMOS EL SUBMIT DEL FORM
$('#formulario').on('submit', function(ev) {

  $.ajax({
    //TOMA LOS ATRIBUTOS DEL FORM CON JQUERY
    //METODO ESPECIFICADO EN TU FORM, POST ,GET
    type: $('#formulario').attr('method'),
    //DIRECCION DE ENVIO DE LA DATA DEL FORM
    url: $('#formulario').attr('action'),
    //TODOS LOS CAMPOS QUE CONTIENE EL FORM
    data: $('#formulario').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
      //ACCION ANTES DE RESOLVER LA PETICION
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //ACCION SI LA PETICION SE RESOLVIO CORRECTAMENTE
    },
    error: function() {
      //ACCION O MENSAJE EN CASO DE FALLAR LA PETICION
    }
  });
  //EVITAMOS EL EVENTO DE REDIRECCION AL ENVIAR FORMULARIO
  ev.preventDefault();
  //LIMPIAMOS EL FORMULARIO, SOLO CAMPOS DE TEXTO
  $("#formulario")[0].reset();
});
```

Este es un pequeño ejemplo, lo puedes adaptar, realiza tus intentos y en base a eso realizas posteriores preguntas.

Comment: no estoy de acuerdo con tu respuesta. primero que nada no implementas un selector delegado... si el form cambia tu ejemplo deja de funcionar

Comment: Acaso el autor de la pregunta indico que su formulario estaba expuesto a cambios?, gracias por tu observación, pero si tienes una mejor respuesta puedes generarla o corregir lo que esta mal de la mía, creo que de eso se trata SO, no solo de opiniones, estamos para apoyarnos y seguir aprendiendo.

Comment: si pero no respondo preguntas basadas en opiniones por este mismo asunto ... que se prestan para debates de que esta bien y que esta mal...

Comment: otra cosa serialize no leera los checkbox no seleccionados.

Comment: Entiendo, en su pregunta no agrega mas detalle ni especificaciones, si gustas mejorar o en su caso corregir la respuesta lo puedes hacer, con esto tiene un parte aguas para comenzar a investigar y si mejoras la respuesta con lo que mencionas excelente. En verdad te agradezco.

Comment: Hola, antes de responder puedes sugerir al OP aclarar su pregunta, las preguntas deben basarse en [ask], ayúdanos a mantener la calidad de la información en el sitio, saludos.

Comment: Claro que si @Jorgesys, considero todos los puntos mencionados, pareciera que somos nosotros los mas interesados que el propio OP.